How to add panning and zoom in blazor web app wasm
I create a new blazor web app project like this: (https://i.sstatic.net/ejiES4vI.png)
It has 2 projects in 1 solution, one is server-side and the other one is client-side. In client-side project there is no such thing "wwwroot/index.html" or "Layout.razor".
I create my own layout like this:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<main>
    <article>
        @Body
    </article>
</main>

When i use this layout i want to use panning and zoom to mouse(with ctrl + mouse wheel). As i see cant do it without javascript code but cant figure out how to do.

Check your Router Component,you could share the layout with:    and configure the default layout with :

When i use this layout i want to use panning and zoom to mouse(with ctrl + mouse wheel). As i see cant do it without javascript code but cant figure out how to do.----The layout component won't affect  panning and zoom ,could you explain your requirement with more details?

There is MainLayout on the server-side but i create my own layout on the client side. I wanted the pages using the layout I created to perform panning and zooming operations, thats it. so I wrote js codes in the code section of the layout I created. When I asked AI, it said I couldn't use the script code like this. It kept saying "write 
there's no index.html since .net 8,you could refer your js codes in app.razor

so should i create my new layout in server-side? and which rendermode type i should use for panning, InteractiveWebAssembly or InteractiveServer?

just select Gobal as interactive location ,I've answered more detailed in another question
